# how to assign default value for arguments when using the new Function method

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

how to assign default value for arguments when using the new Function method?

```
let fileName = "fileone.js", args = [], options = {};
let ls = new Function('fileName', 'args', 'options', 'somefunctionorValue', `....some...code...body...here`)
ls(fileName, args, options)
```

I want to assign the default value for `'someFunctionOrValue'` when the function I am creating is done: `new Function(....)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*assign default value*"? There is no such thing as a "default value" for each parameter. There's a default initaliser expression, which will get evaluated when no (or an `undefined`) argument is provided.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to do it the usual manner, with `=` operator.

```
var sum = new Function('a = 1', 'b = 2', 'return a + b');

console.log(sum()); // Outputs: 3


console.log(sum(5, 7)); // Outputs: 12
```

This is from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function#parameters):

> As the parameters are parsed in the same way as function expressions, whitespace and comments are accepted. For example: "x", "theValue = 42", "[a, b] /* numbers */" — or "x, theValue = 42, [a, b] /* numbers */". ("x, theValue = 42", "[a, b]" is also correct, though very confusing to read.)

Comment: when i am trying to assign a function as a value it is saying the function cannot be defined before instantiation. `new Function('a = 1', 'b = somefunction', 'return someFunction(a + b)');` `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'somefunction' before initialization`

Comment: can you add a js snippe tto your code, i cannot reproduce your issue

Answer (score -2):

Note if you want to use a function from a ANY scope as a default parameter value it won't work as expected:

```js
{
  const def = () => 'test';

  const fn = new Function('fn = def', 'return fn()');

  console.log(fn());
}
```

Unfortunately `new Function` defines a function in a global scope without access to the local scope ‍♂️. You should assign your default value to the global scope (not good):

```js
{
  window.def = () => 'test';

  const fn = new Function('fn = def', 'return fn()');

  console.log(fn());
}
```

Some solution could be to use a symbol (not elegant though):

```js
{
  const id = Math.random().toString().slice(2);
  window[Symbol.for(id)] = () => 'test';

  const fn = new Function(`fn = window[Symbol.for('${id}')]`, 'return fn()');

  console.log(fn());
}
```

Maybe some global object could look better:

```js
{
  
  MyGlobals.def = () => 'test';

  const fn = new Function(`fn = MyGlobals.def`, 'return fn()');

  console.log(fn());
}
```

```html
<script>
window.MyGlobals = {};
</script>
```

Also remember that you can replace `Function` with a function with `eval`. But `eval` will have access to the local scope which could be not preferable in some particular case in your app:

```js
{
  const def = v => v;
  const x = 'test';

  const fn = (fn = def) => eval('fn(x)');

  console.log(fn());
}
```

Avoiding the local scope could be wrapping into `Function`:

```js
{
  const def = () => 'test'; 

  const fn = (fn = def) => (new Function('fn', 'return fn()'))(fn);

  console.log(fn());
}
```

But constructing `Function` every call isn't optimal so the final solution could be:

```js
{
  const def = () => 'test'; 

  const fn = (() => {
    const cached = new Function('fn', 'return fn()');
    return (fn = def) => cached(fn);
  })();

  console.log(fn());
}
```